How to set global config variable for composer in Plesk?
I am trying to install private packages using the composer extension in Plesk, but it keeps complaining about not having access to the respositores.

The 'https://{organization}.repo.repman.io/packages.json' URL could not
be a ccessed (HTTP 403): HTTP/2 403

I already tried to set the correct authorization using this command in SSH
composer config --global --auth http-basic.{organization}.repo.repman.io token e4631126e369cf...

But this doesn't work, I guess it is because I run that command under my own user. I tried to run that command under root, but didn't work either.
Now my guess is that Plesk runs composer commands under its own user, but I cannot seem to figure out what user, or if that is even true.
Someone able to explain how to do this?
